# Expression involving delta function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions

I have to evaluate the object

$$
b(q,m,n)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}k |c_n(w(k,q))|^2J_m(q)\delta(Y_n(w(k,q))-m)
$$

Where $q$ is a continuous variable, $m$, $n$ are integers and

$$
w(k,q)=k^2+q^2
$$

The exact definitions of $c_n$ and $Y_n$ are irrelevant, the important point being that they are both known only numerically (no closed form expression).

Nevertheless in my problem they are

$$
c_n(w)= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}z\, S(b_{2n+2}(w), \frac{1}{w^2}, z) C'(a_0(w), \frac{1}{w^2}, z)
$$

and

$$Y_n(w)=b_{2n+2}(w)-a_0(w)$$

where

$C(a,q,z)$, $S(a,q,z)$ - [Mathieu](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MathieuFunction.html) even and odd functions (aka elliptic cosine and sine functions), $a_0(z)$, $b_{2n+2}(z)$ - [Mathieu characteristic values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function#Periodic_solutions) for even and odd functions.

Here is how I am trying to solve this:

First I define the variables $Y_n, w, c_n$ above

```
w[q_, k_] := q^2+k^2
Y[n_, q_,k_] :=  MathieuCharacteristicB[2 n + 2, w[q,k]] - 
MathieuCharacteristicA[0, w[q,k]]
c[n_,q_,k_] := NIntegrate[MathieuS[MathieuCharacteristicB[2n + 2, w[q,k]], 1/w[q,k]^2, x] MathieuCPrime[MathieuCharacteristicA[0, w[q,k]], 1/w[q,k]^2, x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Until this point everything seems to work fine. I can evaluate the above objects. But then I try to evaluate $b$ using

```
b[q_,m_,n_ ] := Integrate[Abs[c[n,q,k]]^2 BesselJ[m, q] DiracDelta[Y[n,q,k] - m], {k, -Infinity,Infinity}]
```

But this returns the error messages

```
NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand Indeterminate has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,6.8}}. 

NIntegrate::nlim: x = Integrate`ImproperDump`zero is not a valid limit of integration.
```

Any help in overcoming these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please format your code in _Mathematica_ format not $\TeX$

Comment: This is not the code. This is the statement of the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: I've added the code now.

Comment: Your code is garbled. For example `DiracDelta[E_n - m*r}]` makes no sense. Please repair your code and format it for this forum. I suggest you concentrate on the integral containing the delta function.

Comment: I don't think the code is garbled. There was a small typo which you pointed out and which I've corrected. I agree that it would be most fruitful to focus on the integral containing the delta function. But part of the complication is that the integrand depends on the indices which are summed over (n,m) and I must figure out how to handle that.

Comment: You still have the nonsensical `E_n`. Your code is still not formatted for this forum.

Comment: Yup you are right. Made the corrections. Hope this is better.

Comment: @JohnDoty I took your advise and simplified the problem to focus on the delta function.

Comment: Still nonsense. `{}` aren't the same as `()`. Have you used _Mathematica_ before?

Comment: Corrected. No I have not.

Comment: I suggest you learn more _Mathematica_ before attempting to solve a problem this difficult using it.

Comment: I would appreciate specific advice, pertinent to the problem posted above.

Comment: What is `l` in `BesselJ[l, q]` (found in definition of `b`) ?

Comment: Oh gosh another typo. It should be `m`, an integer. Corrected.

Comment: @NirmalyaKajuri FYI, I didn't get notified of that comment, because you didn't tag me in it.

Comment: @jjc385 Sorry, my mistake. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

An extended comment:

Since you're working numerically, a quick and dirty approximation might work.  Simply replace the delta function with an approximation.

For example, you might use (**Edit:** I replaced `DiracDelta` with an undefined function `diracDelta`)

```
diracDelta[x_]:>Exp[-x^2/a^2]/(a Sqrt[Pi]) /. a-> 10^(-15)
```

You can replace `10^(-15)` with whatever value you need for your precision.

Full code:

```
b[q_,m_,n_ ] = Integrate[Abs[c[n,q,k]]^2 BesselJ[l, q] diracDelta[Y[n,q,k] - m]/.diracDelta[x_]:>Exp[-x^2/a^2]/(a Sqrt[Pi]) /. a-> 10^(-15), {k, -Infinity,Infinity}]
```

A few more tips:

- Another approximation (such as a triangle function) might be better suited for your purposes, if the delta function approximation need not be differentiable.
- You might want to use [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html)rather than [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html), if the arguments to `Integrate` are numeric.
- You might want to use `:=` ([`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)) rather than `=` ([`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)).  Your first block of code fails to run unless I make that swap.

There seem to be some problems with your code, making it difficult to run and test this solution.  Could you post a few sets (or ranges) of example parameters `k,q,n`?  Is `k` a continuous variable?  Note that I got an error 
`MathieuCharacteristicB::zord: There is no zero-order MathieuCharacteristicB.`

Comment: Also, welcome to the world of Mathematica!

Comment: Thanks! That is an interesting suggestion, that I will now look into. There were some remaining typos in the code I had presented, which I have now corrected. Now the part before the delta function works fine. `k `and `q` are continuous variables, `n` and `m` are integers.  Thanks again!

Comment: I tried your suggestion, NIntegrating over `k` from -100 to 100. I got 
         `The integrand`    `(1000000000000000E^(-1000000000000000000000000000000 
(-1+Y[1,1,k])^2)\Abs[c[1,1,k]]^2\BesselJ[1,1])/Sqrt[\[Pi]]  has `
`evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the 
region with boundaries {{-100,100}}.`